# How can I get the size of a list in MyBatis xml file?

Tags: mybatis

I have a method in `UserMapper`, which can get a user list related to some labels:

```java
@Mapper
public interface UserMapper {
    List<User> listUsersByLabels(List<String> labels);
}
```

The mapper xml is below:

```xml
<select id="listUsersByLabels" resultType="byx.User">
    SELECT * FROM users
    JOIN labels ON users.id  = labels.user_id
    WHERE labels.title IN
    <foreach collection="labels" open="(" close=")" separator=", " item="title">
        #{title}
    </foreach>
    GROUP BY users.id
    HAVING COUNT(*) = #{labels.size}
</select>
```

I try to use `#{labels.size}` to get the size of list `labels`, but when I call `listUsersByLabels`, it raised an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
### Cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MyBatisExceptionTranslator.java:96)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate$SqlSessionInterceptor.invoke(SqlSessionTemplate.java:441)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy40.selectList(Unknown Source)
    at org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate.selectList(SqlSessionTemplate.java:224)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMany(MapperMethod.java:147)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:80)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy$PlainMethodInvoker.invoke(MapperProxy.java:145)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:86)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy48.listUsersByLabels(Unknown Source)
```

However, when I replace `#{labels.size}` with `${labels.size}`, it works.

Is there a bug in MyBatis?

Comment: It's not a bug. `${}` is evaluated by OGNL whereas `#{}` is evaluated by MyBatis' internal property reference parser which is much simpler. `${labels.size}` is valid because OGNL provides [Pseudo-Properties for collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html#Pseudo-Properties_for_Collections) (as you may be aware, `size` is not a property, it's a method of `java.util.List`).